# Actual inserted row ID

Tags: sql-server, insert

I have created table in my db in this statement

```
CREATE TABLE tPerson
    (
        id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY identity(1,1)
        , name NVARCHAR(100) not null
        , email NVARCHAR(30) not null
    )
GO
```

Now I insert new value with INSERT. My question is how can I get id of current added row? Any idea ??

Comment: Which database? SQL Server? MySQL? Oracle? They have different functions for accomplishing this.

Comment: For SQL Server, see [link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Comment: MS SQL Server 2008 R2 Express

Comment: I would use 70 characters on e-mail column just to be sure. My current work e-mail has 34 characters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming SQL server, you should check out [this article](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/) to gain a good understanding of retrieving identities.

Here's a snippet:

> **SELECT @@IDENTITY**
>
> It returns the last IDENTITY value produced on a
> connection, regardless of the table that produced the value, and
> regardless of the scope of the statement that produced the value.
> @@IDENTITY will return the last identity value entered into a table in
> your current session. While @@IDENTITY is limited to the current
> session, it is not limited to the current scope. If you have a trigger
> on a table that causes an identity to be created in another table, you
> will get the identity that was created last, even if it was the
> trigger that created it.
>
> **SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()**
>
> It returns the last IDENTITY value produced on
> a connection and by a statement in the same scope, regardless of the
> table that produced the value. SCOPE_IDENTITY(), like @@IDENTITY, will
> return the last identity value created in the current session, but it
> will also limit it to your current scope as well. In other words, it
> will return the last identity value that you explicitly created,
> rather than any identity that was created by a trigger or a user
> defined function.
>
> **SELECT IDENT_CURRENT(‘tablename’)**
>
> It returns the last IDENTITY value
> produced in a table, regardless of the connection that created the
> value, and regardless of the scope of the statement that produced the
> value. IDENT_CURRENT is not limited by scope and session; it is
> limited to a specified table. IDENT_CURRENT returns the identity value
> generated for a specific table in any session and any scope.

Comment: And don't forget the OUTPUT clause.  It's reliable!  [Ref Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/328811/scope-identity-sometimes-returns-incorrect-value)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like SQL Server, and it that case, just use:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.tPerson(....) VALUES(.....)

DECLARE @NewID INT
SELECT @NewID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

[`SCOPE_IDENTITY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) returns the last inserted IDENTITY value in this current scope.

Side note: "email" is only 30 characters long!?!? I typically make that the longest column in my table - 200 chars or even more :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use `@@IDENTITY` or `SCOPE_IDENTITY` for MS SQL Server :)

Comment: I would recommend to always use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` - the other options have often unexpected side effects and results....

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT @@IDENTITY AS LastID
```

after your INSERT

Comment: [You should use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` - **not** `@@IDENTITY`](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/) - `@@IDENTITY` can unexpectedly return a wrong result....

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this through JDBC directly to avoid the need to select, as typically an insert statement will return the number of rows inserted which you may want to validate.  Spring supports this through its JdbcTemplate, see [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-auto-genereted-key)